# Monit unable to send email alerts

Tags: centos, email, monit

I have set monit to send email if my java listener failed on port 8000. I have tried to close the listner and run monit validate below is the errors I got.

```
monit validate
'cs8000' process is not running
Sendmail error: 550-Verification failed for <monit@localhost>
Aborting event
monit: Start or stop method not defined -- process cs8000
```

I have set the mailserver as below.

```
set mailserver mail.***.com port 26 username "test1@***.com" password "****" . I am just using the *** to hide the actual name.
```

What else must I set in order for the email to be send out?

Comment: Shouldn't the SMTP port be port 25?

Comment: No is 26 I have tested with simple java application to send email it works.